# laravel 8 npm run undefined operation error

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, npm, webpack

I am trying to work on a laravel 8 upgrade project. I find it painstaking to make the packages work for npm and run my laravel mix in webpack.

Current env:
laravel ^8.6
node - v14.21.3
npm - 6.14.18

Below is my package.json

```
   {
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-scss": "^4.3.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^13.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack": "^5.9.0",
    "webpack-assets-manifest": "^3.1.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-merge": "~5.1.4",
    "axios": "^0.21",
    "laravel-mix": "^4.0.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "2.3.2",
    "sass": "^1.15.2",
    "sass-loader": "7.*",
    "webpack": "^4.0.0"
  },
```

My webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.sourceMaps().disableNotifications().version();
}


/*
 *
 * Slim Theme Publish
 *
 */
mix.sass('Themes/Slim/assets/styles/slim.scss', 'public/themes/slim/css');
```

The error:

```
ERROR in ./Themes/Slim/assets/styles/slim.scss (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--8-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss0!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--8-4!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-5!./Themes/Slim/assets/styles/slim.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):

      line-height: $input-height - .1rem;
                  ^
      Undefined operation "calc(1.5em + 1.188rem + 2px) - 0.1rem".
   ╷
22 │       line-height: $input-height - .1rem;
   │                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  Themes/Slim/assets/styles/lib/_select2.scss 22:20  @import
  stdin 165:9                                        root stylesheet
      in /var/www/html/firmapp.kcmsproject.com/releases/2024-02-25-1253/Themes/Slim/assets/styles/lib/_select2.scss (line 22, column 20)
 @ ./Themes/Slim/assets/styles/slim.scss 2:14-278
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
```

What is the background?
The same scss files ran fine with laravel ver 7 and node 12.

below is my old package.json file which worked for same source files.

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^13.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.5.0",
    "laravel-mix": "^2.1.14",
    "bootstrap-scss": "^4.3.0"
  },
```

Please advise I am too carried away changing all possible combinations of package.json and webpack and sass.

Comment: Try to use `12.16.1` NPM version.